# Embedding xat chat box on a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, embed, chat, xattribute

How can I embed a chat box from xat.com on a Facebook page?

Comment: Have you done anything yet as your own attempt? Did the answer provided help in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Create a facebook page tab application. See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/